# HTML parsing returns no data although they are read

Tags: java, html, parsing, scope, jericho-html-parser

I am having the following problem. I have written a java snippet that reads an html file of known structure(see below). I split it in  elements and get their text using the jericho parser. Then as soon as I print the text to ensure that the retrieval is correct I add each element into an ArrayList(**obviously the retrieval is correct**). As you can guess from the html structure if element i of ArrayList is Email **then element i+1 is the value**. I think its a scope problem but cant figure it out. Can you help? I am using the following code to grab the values:

```
private static void setVariables() 
{
    count=0;
    for(String s:str)
    {

       if(s.contains("Email"))
       {
          email=getValue(email, count);

       }
     }      
}



private static String getValue(String var, int count) 
{
    var=str.get(count+1);
    count++;
    return var;

}




private static void getElementsText(Source source) 
{


    List<Element> elementListTd = source.getAllElements(HTMLElementName.TD);

    //Scroll through the list of elements "td" page
      int i=0;
    for (Element element : elementListTd) {
        if (element.getAttributes() != null) {
            String td = element.getAllElements().toString();
            String tag = "td";
         //   System.out.println("TD: " + td);
          //  System.out.println(element.getContent());
            String contentsAttributes = element.getTextExtractor().toString();
          //  System.out.println("line "+i+" "+contentsAttributes);
            if(!contentsAttributes.isEmpty())
            {   
            str.add(contentsAttributes);
            }


        }
    }

    str.add(" ");
    setVariables();
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{

  FileReader fr=new FileReader("32EPS 2012-ABSTRACT ~ 1333134955.html");
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

  getTextFromFile(br);
  Source source = new Source(html_txt);
  getElementsText(source);

}
```

HTML:

```
<tr><td class='text11' nowrap>Email</td><td class='text11'>peraueb@dummy.com<td></tr>
<tr><td class='text11' nowrap>Gender</td><td class='text11'>Mr<td></tr>
```

Comment: You haven't posted enough code for us to help

Comment: Ok, I will edit now. Please remove the negative vote

Comment: Try to keep your code appropriately formatted. Use four spaces before each line of code.